# Are Saved Posts completely private from the post author?

Tags: facebook

I know that Saved Items are on a list "[that only [I] can see](https://www.facebook.com/help/220284408163249)." But is the author of the post aware of when their post is added?

[image: Facebook Webapp Saved Post Feature]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my experiment, yes, they are private. When you save an item the author will not be notified.

[image: evidence that saves are private]

Comment: Yes they are aware or yes they are private? Question title does not match the body in what you're asking.

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise I meant they're private, because my buddy said he wasn't aware that I'd saved some of his posts while I had him sitting on Facebook. Always love seeing edits to improve answers, please feel free.